# What is the use of read.partitions optin when read parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have found the below code segment to read parquet files using pyspark.

`df = spark.read.format('parquet').option("read.partitions", "6").load(pq_loc)`

But I couldn't find any reference regarding `option("read.partitions", "6")`. What is the use of this option? And is there any place to find all the available options for reading from the parquet?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below documentation for reading `parquet` files using pyspark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html

`option` is generally used to specific how you want to read the files, here `"read.partitions", "6"` means that you want to read the file in 6 parts.